# Find the minimum of an integral based function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

minimize $$\int_0^1 y(t)\sqrt{1+(y'(t))^2} \,dt$$

such that y(0) = y(1) = 0
and 
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(y'(t))^2} \,dt = 2$$

EDIT: I tried using the Euler Lagrange relations and came up with this equation:

$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{yy'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}$ = $\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$ which leads to

$yy'= (1+(y')^2)t$

I don't know where to go from here.

EDIT 2: I followed up with notes on Beltrami identity and here is what I got and where I am currently stuck at:

$y\sqrt{1+y'^2} - yy'^2 = a\sqrt{1+y'^2}$

$y = a\sqrt{1+y'^2}$

$\frac{y}{a} = \sqrt{1+y'^2}$

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{y}{a} \,dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(y'(t))^2} \,dt = 2$$

I am not sure where to go from $$ \int_0^1 \frac{y}{a} \,dt = 2$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Botond added an edit outlining my process.

Comment: Your lagrange function is $L=y\sqrt{1+y'^2}+\lambda\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ because the constraint.

Comment: @Botond that does not change things much. I still end with the final equation but instead of $yy' = (1+y')^2)t$, I now have  $(y+\lambda)y' = (1+y')^2)t$

Comment: There should be no explicit $t$ in the differential equation. You can't just integrate as $y(t)$ depends on $t$.

Comment: @Winther that makes sense. Where do I go from that step?

Comment: Did you do the differentiation right? I didn't do it myself, but you should get a second order diff. eq.

Comment: Use the [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) to get a simple(r) ODE. The integral is the surface area when the function $y(t)$ is rotated about the $t$-axis. Thus you want to minimize the area of this surface while keeping the arclength fixed. See this for a similar problem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurfaceofRevolution.html

Comment: @Winther this is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Winther I am still stuck because part of the solution approach does not include the dependence of y on t and I need to make use of my boundary conditions and integral value provided, which I can't do if I follow their last step of resolving the answer in terms of t. I explained my process more in the edit.

Comment: Write it as $y'/g(y) =1$ for some function $g$ and integrate this equation as written. Perhaps easier to see when written as $dy/g(y) = dt$.